# Show that $\displaystyle f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1+n^2x^2}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Trying to use the definition of uniform convergence where $|f_n(x) \to f(x)| \to 0$ as $n \to$ ∞ but not sure how to apply this definition to the problem

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Compute $\sup_x f_n(x)$ for each $n$, by finding the maximum of $f_n$ via its critical points, the roots of $f_n'$.

Comment: Ok thanks, is this correct? $f_n(x) = x/(1+n^2x^2)$  so $f_n'(x) = (1+n^2x^2)/(1+n^2x^2)^2$, when $f_n'(x) = 0, then 1-n^2x^2 = 0$,   then x = +1/n or x = -1/n, $lim 1/n, n \to ∞ = 0$

Comment: No, not correct, but parts of it are. So you found that $f_n$ has its critical point at $x_n = \frac 1n$ (note that $-\frac 1n \not\in [0,\infty)$. To show uniform convergence, you have to prove $f_n(x_n) = \sup_x f_n(x) \to 0$